# Everything is just Orange. Shockwave missing beats

Tags: animation, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, color

Can someone help me. I'm new to this and have made it far in 2 weeks, but being I am not an expert I've finally hit a dead end. If someone could help me, or flat out correct the 2 problems I'm having and tell me how you did it so I'll know next time, that would be great.

1.) Everything in my project is Orange and I only want my Shockwave, Wings, and Glowing Outline of my letters Orange like in my screenshot below (everything else comes out orange except my A). My big A is rendering all black and wont take on a color at all.

2.) My created Shockwave hits on beat in the Animation and Vid tabs, but when I render it and open the file for playback its hitting late and then starts playing choppy (out of sync altogether).

I have screen shots of the COMP. view, but as far as my Shockwave the screenshots wont tell you much you'll have to play it yourself. I really would love to finish my intro like this weekend coming up as I want to post a video on the 4th. If you think you can assist me let me know. I can send the rest of the screenshots. The actual project file is available below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since there is a lot going on I'm going to break it down into bullets.

1. The black A: Lights don't go across layers. Layer one with the A has no lights causing the A to be black.
2. Everything is orange because you only have one render layer and do the compositing to the whole scene. You need to make a non orange render layer and have it alpha over in the compositor. See the below images:

Settings for orange layer. Notice how only the second layer is selected.
[image]

Settings for non orange layer. Notice how only the first layer is selected. Also turn **OFF** sky.

[image]

I'm not sure why you have additional compositing to the viewer I ignored that. Coming out of your current final node use an alpha over to combine the render layers.

[image]

3. I don't do audio in Blender so I can't help you there.

Comment: About to give this a try now.

Comment: @AGodOfKings It work for you?